# Why does this compare answer never change?

Tags: c#

I'm writing code that reads a CSV into an array. The 7th item in the CSV is `TenNinetyNine` or `W2` so I compare `array[6]` and `TenNinetyNine` and it always gives me 1 back saying they match. I pull up a messagebox with `array[6]` and it shows that they don't match.

I have tried: `if (array[6] == "TenNinetyNine")` and using `string.Compare` which is currently up.

I messed with the CSV which was originally 1099 or W2 just to verify they both read in as strings. All my testing shows that every line I see a new value for `array[6]` but it seems to keep the first result when they are compared.

```
string data = sr.ReadLine();
while (data != null)
{
    string[] developerData = data.Split(',');
    string tax1 = "TenNinetyNine";
    int taxCompared = string.Compare(tax1, developerData[6]);

    MessageBox.Show(developerData[6]); //Changes each iteration
    MessageBox.Show(taxCompared.ToString()); //Always 1
}
```

I expect the `MessageBox.Show(taxCompared.ToString());` to produce a 1 for `TenNinetyNine` and a -1 (or 0) for `W2`.

Comment: "and it always gives me 1 back saying they match", that's not at all what String.Compare does, I am not sure from where did you get that wrong information.  ["Compares two specified String objects and returns an integer that indicates their relative position in the sort order."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare). `String.Compare` is useful for ordering strings in an array. `String.Equals` (or just `==`) is what you are after

Answer (score 2):

Put a breakpoint on the first messagebox so that you can hove over and see **tax1** and **developerData[6]** are identical as I have no idea what developerData[6] is returning.  String.Compare is case sensitive so check for that too, ensure there are no leading or trailling spaces by trimming each string:

```
int taxCompared = string.Compare(tax1.Trim(), developerData[6].Trim();
```

Comment: Vote me up then :-)